# Only Update Table if Field is NULL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query which is working OK

```
    UPDATE Master 
    SET Closed = Date(), 
        Status = 'Closed', 
        [Closure Reason] = 'Not on Extract'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                       FROM Extract
                       WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case 
                     );
```

I need to amend it to add another criteria, ie ONLY do the update if the value of Master.[Closure Reason] is NULL

But this gives a syntax error:

```
UPDATE Master SET Closed = Date(), Status = 'Closed', [Closure Reason] = 'Not on Extract'
WHERE [Closure Reason] = "" AND
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Extract
                  WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case
                 );
```

I've tried using IS NULL rather than = "" to no avail.

What is wrong with it please?

Comment: `IS NULL` should work for what you want to do.  You should show the query with that construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Master SET Closed = Date(), Status = 'Closed', [Closure Reason] = 'Not on Extract'
WHERE [Closure Reason] IS NULL 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Extract
                  WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case
                 );
```

You can't add multiple `WHERE` clauses, you need to use the `AND`. If your requirement is "ONLY do the update if the value of Master.[Closure Reason] is NULL", then check for `NULL`, not for an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @JaydipJ, missed the extra `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the second `where` before `not exists`.

```
UPDATE Master SET Closed = Date(), Status = 'Closed', [Closure Reason] = 'Not on Extract'
WHERE [Closure Reason] = "" AND
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Extract
                  WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `AND` conditional operator instead of having two `WHERE` clauses like

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Extract
                  WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case
                 )
AND [Closure Reason] IS NULL;
```